# Join tables from different Glue catalogs with PySpark on EMR

Tags: pyspark, amazon-emr, aws-glue

To query a Glue Catalog from PySpark on EMR, I set the parameter `hive.metastore.glue.catalogid` in my cluster configuration.

Is it possible to join tables from **different Glue catalogs** (on different AWS accounts) ?

I tried to create a view with Athena from one AWS tenant to the other, but apparently PySpark is not able to query SQL views.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible in Pyspark by setting the catalog separator config.

```
pyspark --conf spark.hadoop.aws.glue.catalog.separator="/"
```

The desired catalogs can then be selected directly from your Pyspark sql query. Note the catalog id (account id) is delimited by the separator `/`:

```
spark.sql(select * from `111122223333/demodb.tab1` t1 inner join  `444455556666/demodb.tab2` t2 on t1.col1 = t2.col2).show()
```

[Source AWS Doc](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/query-glue-data-catalog-cross-account/)